# Переход по ссылке при нажатии "пробел"

Tags: html, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток (второй раз за сегодня 8-) )

Есть страничка, на ней до хрена всего, и есть определенная ссылка. Как сделать, что бы при нажатии "пробел" был переход по этой ссылке?

з.ы. Естественно охота без дополнительных библиотек, и максимально коротко.

з.з.ы. На этой странице уже есть форма, так что сделать из ссылки форму, и переделывать на нажатие ентер'ом - не вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только печатать будет трудно.

```
window.onkeyup = function(e){
    var k = e.keyCode;
    if(k == 32){
        // нажат пробел
        location.href = document.getElementById('linka').href;
    }
}
```

Comment: k = e.keyCode || e.which;  
А это еще зачем? Разве кейКод не всеми браузерами поддерживается?
Вроде, только на чарКод есть ограничения.

Comment: Да, спасибо. =) Перепутал немного.

Answer (score 2):

```
<body onkeypress="if(window.event.keyCode==32){window.location='http://example.com'}">
```

Пользователи вас возненавидят.

Comment: Что возненавидят, так это точно.

Answer (score 0):

извиняюсь, не понял, это все я прописываю, не работает (

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onkeyup = function(e){
  var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(k == 32){
    location.href = document.getElementById('http://ya.ru').href;
  }
}
</script>
```

а если мне в место http://ya.ru нужно "fid".$num."one.php",  как быть?

Comment: linka в комментарии ling'a (выбрал же человек айдишник, а) - это ID необходимой ссылки. То есть, у вас на странице должна быть  
<a href='"fid".$num."one.php"' id='linka'>SOME_TEXT</a>

Comment: да, понял. все супер. спасибо